# Problems forwarding port 3306 on iptables with CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos, iptables, port-forwarding

Im trying to add a forward to the mysql server at 200.58.126.52 to allow the access from 200.58.125.39, and Im using the following rules (its my whole iptables of the VPS of my hosting). I can connect locally at the server that holds the mysql service as localhost, but not from outside.

Can someone check if the following rules are fine? Thank you

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-securitylevel
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 51 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -s 200.58.125.39 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 200.58.125.39 --sport 1024:65535 -d localhost --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -s localhost --sport 3306 -d 200.58.125.39 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

And this is the output of the connection trial.

[root@qwhosti /home/qwhosti/public_html/admin/config] # mysql -u user_db -p -h 200.58.126.52
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '200.58.126.52' (113)

Comment: This would be a lot easier to read, had you left out the irrelevant (for this question) rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your new rule on the `RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` chain BEFORE the `-j REJECT` rule.  Rules are read from top to bottom, first one that matches gets applied; since there is no specifier on the `REJECT` rule, your incoming connections get `REJECT`ed before they can be forwarded.